# add another html tag after li element in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation, footer

I have a nav menu in footer. I just want to display it side by a `<p>` tag, I mean something like this

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>copyright C 2021</p>
</li>
<li>
contact
</li>
<li>
blog
</li>
</ul>
```

this is my menu function

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'top_nav_menu' => 'My Footer Menu'
        )
    );
```

and I'm calling it in footer

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top_nav_menu' ) ) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu' => 'Footer Navigation Menu', 
                'theme_location' => 'top_nav_menu', 
                'menu_class' => 'footer-links'
                )); 
            ?>
            <?php } else {?>
            <ul class="sf-menu">
                <?php wp_list_pages( array('title_li' => '','sort_column' => 'menu_order')); ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
```

How can I insert an extra **`<li>`** element just before its first **`<li>`** and add a **`<p>`** tag between that later added **`<li>`** element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `wp_nav_menu()` you can exclude the `<ul>` tag by setting the `items_wrap` to only include the list items (`%3$s`), then you can add your own `<li>` before or after that, and wrap it with `<ul>` yourself:

```
<ul class="footer-links">
    <li>
        <p>copyright C 2021</p>
    </li>

    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( 
        array(
            'menu'           => 'Footer Navigation Menu', 
            'theme_location' => 'top_nav_menu', 
            'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
        )
    );
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the HTML output with the [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/) filter. Using [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
add_action( 'wp_nav_menu', 'wpse_385827_filter_nav_menu' );
function wpse_385827_filter_nav_menu( $menu ) {
    $menu = preg_replace(
               '|<li>|',
               '<li><p>Your inserted content here</li><li>', 
               $menu, 
               1
    );

    return $menu;
}
```

**Note:** The `1` parameter in the `preg_replace()` call ensures that only the first `<li>` tag is affected.